# How do I install Open Modelsphere in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I install Open Modelsphere in Ubuntu 12.04? What packages do I need to install and what launch script do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Using [this hint](http://sarithdivakar.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/how-to-install-open-model-sphere-in.html) as a starting point, I added the following item to the classpath list:

```
/usr/share/java/jgrapht0.8.jar
```

(I also had to install the packages `libjgrapht-java` and `openjdk-7-jre` which you may already have.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the following contents into the root folder of the program, and execute this.
Ex. $vim model.sh  # put content
    $./model.sh

```
path="./lib/jgrapht-all/jgrapht-all.jar\
 ./lib/ojdbc6.jar ./modelsphere.jar ./plugins/bin/repository_functions.jar \
 ./resources.zip ./lib/jakarta-regexp-1.5/jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar \
 ./lib/velocity-1.6.1/velocity-1.6.1.jar \
 ./lib/jazzy-core/jazzy-core.jar \
 ./lib/jython-2.2.1/jython.jar \
 ./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar \
 ./lib/velocity-1.6.1/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar \
 ./lib/lablib-checkboxtree-3.0.2.jar"
libs=".:./resources:./targets"
for x in $path
do
  if [ ! -f $x ] 
  then
     echo "File not found [$x]"
     exit 1
  else
     libs="$libs:$x"
  fi
done
java -ms64m -mx512m -ss16m -classpath "$libs" org.modelsphere.sms.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command line which worked for version 3.2.2:

> java -ms64m -mx512m -ss16m -cp .:./modelsphere.jar:./resources.zip:./resources:./targets:./lib/jakarta-regexp-1.5/jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar:./lib/jython-2.2.1/jython.jar:./lib/jgrapht-all/jgrapht-all.jar:./lib/* org.modelsphere.sms.Application